# Folder level from GIT checkout on teamcity agent

Tags: git, bitbucket, perforce, dvcs, teamcity-9.1

We have been tasked to move our source code from perforce to bitbucket recently. our perforce repository is quite huge and has multiple modules which are segregated in different folders . So far we have been using the VCS and checkout rules in TC to checkout only the relevant codes an build it.
However i am not sure if there are any such possibilities with GIT given that folder level checkout is currently not supported by GIT Teamcity integration.

Can someone please let me know how best we can achieve it from teamcity ? Breaking down our repository into multiple ones is a huge task given the age and complexity of the code base

Comment: My company is going through a very similar situation (P4 --> Bitbucket Server). Git is so different in scope and approach from Perforce that the problem has proved to be a hard nut to crack.